# How to run a FileSensor inside of an Airflow task?

Tags: python, airflow

Airflow version: 2.8

I'm struggling to run a `FileSensor` inside a DAG in Airflow. I built a generic `FileSensor` *generator*:

```py
def generic_human_feedback_sensor(step_name: str) -> FileSensor:
    prefix = ""
    run_id = str(os.getenv("AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID"))
    if os.getenv("FILE_STORAGE_LAYER_ENV") == "local":
        pythonpath = os.getenv("PYTHONPATH")
        prefix = f"{pythonpath}/data/s3/"
        fs_connection_id = "fs_default"
    else:
        fs_connection_id = "aws_s3_log"

    definitions_validated_by_humans = prefix + f"input/{step_name}/{run_id}/**.json"
    return FileSensor(
        task_id=f"{step_name}_human_feedback",
        filepath=definitions_validated_by_humans,
        mode="poke",
        timeout=300,
        poke_interval=60,
        fs_conn_id=fs_connection_id,
        recursive=True,
    )
```

This method should be able to return a `FileSensor` operator to the DAG it runs in:

```py
@dag(
    dag_id="main",
    schedule=None,
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2021, 1, 1, tz="UTC"),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["main"],
    params={"pdf_path": Param("path to a pdf to run the DAG on.")},
)
def main():
    ...
    definitions_sensor = generic_human_feedback_task(step_name="text_to_definitions")
    definitions_sensor.set_upstream(previous_task)
    if definitions_sensor is True:
        logging.error("File found")
```

Here's the thing: I don't know how to check whether the sensor has found the file or not. The documentation indicates that the sensor will return True if the file is found but the log isn't triggered even if the DAG logs indicate that the file was found:

```
[2024-02-02, 18:35:16 CET] {base.py:83} INFO - Using connection ID 'fs_default' for task execution.
[2024-02-02, 18:35:16 CET] {filesystem.py:66} INFO - Poking for file data/s3/input/<step name>/None/**.json
[2024-02-02, 18:35:16 CET] {filesystem.py:71} INFO - Found File data/s3/input/<step name>/None/some_file.json last modified: 20240201184050
```

P.S: I know that Airflow injects some env vars, does somebody know why I can't seem to extract the `AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID` env var?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: for starters, can you check the airflow UI to see if the DAG task has passed or not?

Comment: the task has passed indeed, it's green and was displaying the messages that I provided in the post.

Comment: You are tring to get AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID while dag parse and not running. You can create a tesk that while running make the decision and returns fs_connection_id to xcom and then use it in the filesensor

Comment: thx for your answer @ozs. the fs_connection_id is based on some basic condition irrelevant to airflow env vars, but i'll note what you said about the run id.  but once the file sensor finds a file, how am I supposed to check? is my logic to return a generic file sensor compatible with airflow ?